# jQuery access element after changing ID

Tags: jquery, dom

I am updating the ID of an element but I can't select it by jQuery after that.

```
console.log($("#tab-" + idOld + "-image-path"));
$("#tab-" + idOld + "-image-path").attr("id", "#tab-" +idNew + "-image-path");
console.log($("#tab-" + idNew + "-image-path"));
```

The first console log outputs

```
Object { 0: <input#tab-63-image-path>, length: 1, context: HTMLDocument → Settings, selector: "#tab-63-image-path" }
```

while the second one outputs

```
Object { context: HTMLDocument → Settings, selector: "#tab-63-image-path" }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `attr("id", "#tab-" +idNew + "-image-path");` should not have the # - @Satpal attr or prop makes no difference, but prop is recommended

Comment: Try `$("#tab-" + idOld + "-image-path").prop("id", "tab-" +idNew + "-image-path");`

Comment: @mplungjan post this as answer and I will mark it as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try without the # in the value

```
$("#tab-" + idOld + "-image-path").prop("id", "tab-" +idNew + "-image-path");
```

or

```
var $elem = $("#tab-" + idOld + "-image-path");
$elem.prop("id", $elem[0].id.replace(idOld,idNew));
```

Comment: The first one solved it. I had simply mixed up jQuery selector (where you need the `#` if you want to select by id) and property value (where you have "id" as property name)